# Why doesn’t the "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" AAD endpoint work, while the "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant ID]" does?

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal

I’m developing a **UWP** application that calls an **API**. The API is made of an **Azure Function** triggered by HTTP requests. I want the Azure Function to be secured through **Azure Active Directory**. To do so, I created **two** app registrations in AAD, one for the UWP and one for the API. Both support accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - **Multitenant**) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g., Skype, Xbox). The API app registration provides **scope**, and the UWP app registration uses that scope. The code I use on my UWP is:

```
var HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
const string clientId      = "[UWP app registration’s client ID]";
const string authority     = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Tenant ID of the UWP app registration]";
string[] scopes            = { "api://[API app registration’s client ID]/[scope]" };

var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
             .Create(clientId)
             .WithAuthority(authority)
             .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
             .Build();

AuthenticationResult result;
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

try {
   result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException) {
   try {
      result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
   }
   catch (Exception exception) {
      Console.WriteLine(exception);
      throw;
   }
}

if (result == null) return;
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
 var response = _httpClient.GetAsync("[API URL]").Result;
```

This code works, but if I replace the `authority` with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` (as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#authority)), being my app registrations multi-tenant, I get a **401** response when calling the API `_httpClient.GetAsync("[API URL]").Result`. [The docs say the code must be updated somehow when using the `/common` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values), but I don’t understand how I should edit it. I also tried to follow [these tips](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2#alternate-approach-to-use-withdefaultredirecturi), but without success, while [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet#constraints) seem not to be related to my case since I’m not building an IWA. If I run the working version of the code, `result` is populated with an object whose `TenantId` property gets the right value of the tenant that owns the app registrations while using the not-working version of the code, `result` is populated with an object whose `TenantId` property gets a value I don’t know where it’s coming from.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my understanding of AAD multitenancy flow :

The common authority can't be used to get a token. It's used as a common endpoint to get the templated server metadata :

- v1 : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration
- v2 : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

A token should be requested from the issuer where the client is defined.

But the common authority can be used in a multitenant API (eg your Azure Functions API) to verify that a client has a valid AAD token. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values) :

> Because the /common endpoint doesn’t correspond to a tenant and isn’t an issuer, when you examine the issuer value in the metadata for /common it has a templated URL instead of an actual value : [https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/](https://sts.windows.net/%7Btenantid%7D/)
>
> Therefore, a multi-tenant application can’t validate tokens just by matching the issuer value in the metadata with the issuer value in the token. A multi-tenant application needs logic to decide which issuer values are valid and which are not based on the tenant ID portion of the issuer value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I verify that a client has a valid AAD token?

Comment: In your API you should use a custom validation to check the issuer. Documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#customizing-token-validation

Comment: Instead of `https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/`, I get something like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[unknown tenant]/v2.0` when using the `/common` endpoint. Where does that “unknown tenant” come from?

Comment: You are using the v2 token endpoint. sts.windows.net/{tenantid} is the v1 issuer. You can open the two OAuth2 config files that I pointed below, and look at the issuer part.
I think you are not familiar with the AAD OAuth2 complexity (different versions, single/multi tenants, scope/claim validations). I suggest you to try the single tenant before converting it to a multi tenant API.

Comment: You’re right; I’m not. Unfortunately, these are my company’s requests. Anyway, thanks for your responses.